# Brother MFC-295CN installation help needed

Tags: installation, 13.04, brother

I am a complete NEWBIE to Linux and Ubuntu. So I need step by step help please. I am running Ubuntu 13.04 and I have no clue how to install my printer. I am sick of Windows and want to run Ubuntu only, but right now I have to dual boot with Windows so I have access to my printer. Printer is a Brother MFC-295CN, and I want to install basic way by USB-not network. I have looked at other questions about this but I don't understand how to install packages or use terminal commands. So a step by step help is what I need. Thanks in advance for any help.